# Set widget on a Flextable

Tags: java, gwt

I have this code that I use to render product in a grid layout using a FlexTable:

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<Long, Product> mp) {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            GWT.log("Success list all products count="+mp.size());

            Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator(); 
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

                Product product = (Product) pairs.getValue();
                ProductWidget pw = productInstance.get();
                pw.setTitle(product.getName());
                pw.setImageUrl(product.getImageUrl());
                pw.setContent(product.getInfo());

                flextable.setWidget(i, j, pw);
                i = j > 3 ? i : i++;
                j++;
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }   

        }
```

The `Map` mp returned `4` Products to be rendered as widget, however only `3` gets rendered on the Flextable, what could be wrong in this code?

Comment: 'i = j > 3 ? i : i++;
                j++;' what exactly you doing by this code? 
Please specify your requirement , aligning the products into a 3x3 metrics?

Comment: yes 3x3, I actually solved this already, but answers will be appreciated...

Comment: actually its 3 cols, and any number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flextable.setWidget(i, j, pw);
i = j > 2 ? i++:i;
j = j > 2 ? 0 : j++;
```

I think this will make it. 3 col and infinite rows.